# Derivation of M step in Gaussian EM-Algorithm (Maximize a given function for 2 parameters).

Tags: calculus, statistics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, machine-learning

## Question

The Expectation-maximization algorithm is an alternating algorithm. This means that it alternates between the M-step (maximization step) and the E-step (expectation step). My question is how does one get the maximization step in the context of this notation. I have found the EM algorithm's definition discussed in [Bishop's Pattern Recognition and machine learning on page 438 in 2 alternative forms](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) and a derivation on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-q0KFRaPuvc) using similar notation. The [full derivation of the E step and the maximization of the E-step with regards to $\pi_{j}$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473399/derivation-of-m-step-for-gaussian-mixture-model).

In my notation I had finished the E step as

\begin{align}
= \sum_{i=1}^{n}W_{i1} \left(log (1-\sum_{j=2}^{K}\pi_j)  -\frac{1}{2} log(|\Sigma_1|) -\frac{d}{2} log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_1)^{T} \Sigma_{1}^{-1}(x_i-\mu_1) \right)+ 
     \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=2}^{K} W_{ij} \left( log(\pi_j) -\frac{1}{2} log (|\Sigma_j|) -\frac{d}{2} log(2\pi) -\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu_j)^{T} \Sigma_{j}^{-1}(x_i-\mu_j)\right)
\end{align}

The next step would be the M step, which put simply is maximizing the above function in terms of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$.

## Summary

How do I maximize the above function with regards to $\mu$ and $\Sigma$. I am making a few mistakes in my attempts and would like to please see how this is done.